# AutoMapper: manually set property

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using AutoMapper to map from flat DataObjects to fat BusinessObjects and vice versa. I noticed that mapping from DataObjects to BusinessObjects takes extra time because of change notification of the BusinessObjects (implements INotifyPropertyChanged with custom validation, etc).

Because I normally don't need change notification during mapping, I'd like to turn it off. So I added a property "IsPropertyChangedEnabled". If this property is set to false, no NotifyPropertyChanged event is not raised and time is saved.

Question:

Can I tell AutoMapper to set this property to false at the very beginning of the mapping process? If so, how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use `BeforeMap` method to set property value before mapping process:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
      .BeforeMap((s, d) => d.IsPropertyChangedEnabled = false );
```

Comment: Two minutes? Why did you let me wait that long?    :-)

P.S.: The "AfterMap" method I found myself
P.P.S.: Thank you!

Comment: BTW you can use `AfterMap` to enable event raising after properties were initialized.

Comment: for me this cause an error: "expression tree cannot contain an assignment operator". why didn't you get this error?

Answer (score 54):

You can also use ForMember() which has the added benefit of passing the standard unit test   of Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid() when the properties being set to values are not in the source object.

here's an example

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ClientData, GenerateClientLetterCommand>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom( o => Guid.NewGuid()))
            .ForMember(x => x.Created, opt => opt.MapFrom( o => DateTime.Now));
```

Assign value on basis of condition

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ClientData, GenerateClientLetterCommand>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Gender, opt => opt.MapFrom( o => o.Gender == 0 ? "Male" : "Female"));
```

Comment: Just wanted to warn that `UseValue()` results in a static value being mapped. So in the answer here, `GenerateClientLetterCommand.Created` is going to be always set to a single `DateTime` value from when the AutoMapper is initialized, even on repeated invocations! Got bit by a bug with that, so wanted that in.

Comment: This method works perfectly for `private set` properties

Comment: @SandeepPhadke I think the updated answer will work well.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from the description is that you don't want to fire the property change notification while fetch data from db using the DO and filling the BO.

One possible solution for this would be to have a base class for all BO having two major functionality, 1. Property - IsLoaded which will be set by the mapper after the data is loaded and 2. INotifyPropertyChange implementation and a method to wrap the RaisePropertyChange publisher to check the IsLoaded property and raise the event based on that.

Comment: Hm, still thinking about this. In the constructor I used to raise the propertychanged-event to trigger validation and thus invalidate all fields not allowed to be null, etc. When a property was set (with or without AutoMapper) the propertychanged-event was raised again, re-validation occured and everything was fine. Now the re-validation does not occur, because of I turn if off using the BeforeMap of Automapper. Stil have to think about how I best resolve this.