# Ignore mapping an event with Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper, eventhandler

I have to two same objects (`A` , `B`). I want map all of `A` properties to `B` properties but i want ignore `PropertyChanged` event while mapping.

The signature of `PropertyChanged` is:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

My `B` object has some values in `PropertyChanged` befor mapping but the following code cause: `B.PropertyChanged == Null`:

```
B = Mapper.Map<myClass, myClass>(A);
```

I tried this one:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<myClass, myClass>().ForMember(x => x.PropertyChanged, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

But i get this error:

> ... PropertyChanged can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=
>   ...

How can i ignore mapping an event handler property with Automapper???

Comment: possible duplicate of [AutoMapper: manually set property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277904/automapper-manually-set-property)

Comment: No, i want prevent event mapping but your link question is about preventing OnPropertyChanged inside the source object.

Comment: @shahkalpesh, my question is different!

Comment: Can't you just omit the `Ignore`? I think AM doesn't try to copy events anyway. It only copies properties.

Comment: @GertArnold, why B.PropertyChanged changs to NULL after mapping by this code in my app?: B = Mapper.Map<myClass, myClass>(A);

Comment: You might need to disable the event for the data loading as mentioned by the link by @shahkalpesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong mapping statement.

```
B = Mapper.Map<myClass, myClass>(A);
```

creates a **new `B` object**. The previous object is gone. Obviously the new `B` doesn't have an event handler.

Instead you should use

```
Mapper.Map(A, B);
```

Now the *existing* `B` receives `A`'s values and you'll see that `B`'s `PropertyChanged` event(s) will fire.