# How to change a property while mapping using Automapper?

Tags: c#, list, automapper

Here are the two classes that I am using for Automapper

```
class A {
    Guid id,
    int a,
    int b,
    int c
}

class B {
        Guid id,
        int a,
        int b,
        int c,
        int d

    }
```

I am creating a list by mapping one of the above classes
Here is the code:

```
 AList = Mapper.Map<List<B>, List<A>>(item);
```

But the issue I am facing is the property `Guid id` needs to be unique everytime in the list i.e it should be `Guid.NewGuid()` in every object of the list. But once it is automapped how should I access it and change. I am avoiding using `foreach` since it is the only reason I opted for `AutoMapper`

Comment: What does this mean: `But once it is automapped how should I access it and change` ?

Comment: After  `AList = Mapper.Map<List<B>, List<A>>(item);` statement, I cannot access the property unless I use `foreach` which I am avoiding to use..

Comment: What do you mean you cannot access the property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AutoMapper: manually set property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277904/automapper-manually-set-property)

Comment: You can set the id in the B constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to map an A to a B but to give B a new Guid for an id. This code should work:

```
var a = new A() { id = Guid.NewGuid(), a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 };
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => 
    cfg.CreateMap<A, B>()
        .ForMember(d => d.id, o => o.UseValue(Guid.NewGuid()))
);
var b = Mapper.Map<B>(a);
```

That mapping configuration tells AutoMapper to use a new Guid for `b.id` every time you map an `A` to a `B`.

**Edit:** If you step through this in the debugger, you'll see that the two objects have the same values for properties `a`, `b`, and `c`, but different Guids for the `id` property.

Comment: So why would you do this with AM? Constructors are for initializing members.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I don't understand your point. He's mapping an `A` to a `B`, but he wants to do something different with the `id` property. I can use the `B` constructor to set a new Guid, but then I have to tell the mapping configuration not to map the `id` property, so it doesn't save me any code. And maybe there's another scenario where the OP does not want to initialize `B` with a new Guid, so the constructor shouldn't do that. Am I missing something?

Comment: An object should encapsulate its behavior. Having an id is a property of the object, not of the mapping. Having no setter would make sure AM won't touch it.

Comment: Yes, thanks, good point – I hadn't thought about about making the `id` property readonly, but that does work. However, it also involves changing the design of the class, which may or may not work for the OP.